# C# & SQL Server : add parameter to query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this query (not important per se):

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE " +
"CONTAINS((col1, col2, col3), " +  "'\"*m*\"' )" +   
"ORDER BY(SELECT null) " + 
"OFFSET(1) ROWS  FETCH NEXT(100) ROWS ONLY", conn);
```

It returns all rows that have an 'm' in the specified columns, as it should.
Notice that the 'm' is inside a pair of asterisks (wild characters), then quotation marks, then apostrophes.

I wanted to parametrize it, i.e. put any string in the query.

I wrote this:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE "+ "CONTAINS((col1, col2, col3), " +    "'\"*@searchText*\"' )" +  
"ORDER BY(SELECT null) "+ 
"OFFSET(1) ROWS  FETCH NEXT(100) ROWS ONLY", conn);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchText", textToSearch);
```

But instead of putting the `textToSearch` string's contents in the `SqlCommand`, this code puts `@searchText` itself.

I looked similar posts here and tried to follow but it did not work, probably because there is an apostrophe and a quotation mark and an asterisk in the format.

What am I doing wrong?

How should I specify this command?

Comment: Why are you wrapping `@searchText` in `*`? Sorry if this is obvious, I don't claim to know everything.

Comment: You're saying `CONTAINS((col1, col2, col3), '"*@searchText*"')` in your string.

Comment: This is how it works, I tested it in SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are enclosing your parameter inside single quotes which are reserved for character strings.

Remove the single quotes around the parameter and you should be fine like so:

Yours:

```
+ "'\"@searchText\"' )" +
```

Correct:

```
+ " @searchText)" +
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to include the double quotes and asterisk in what you are searching for, you'll want to concatenate the string in SQL like so:

```
+ "'\"*' + @searchText + '*\"')" +
```

**EDIT2**:

Per @steve's suggestion:

```
textToSearch = "'\"*" + textToSearch + "*\"'"
```

Then, you can leave your SQL as this which is much more readable.

```
+ " @searchText)" +
```

Comment: Perhaps it is better to prepare correctly the _textToSearch_ variable instead of complicating the query text.

Comment: I added additional apostrophes, which was the error. Removing them and leaving only the quotation marks and the asterisk fixed the problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the parameter into your search string in the query... something like this:

```
"'\"*' + @searchText + '*\"' )"
```

Comment: It's the same as your edited answer. I didn't test, so please give the error and correct yours too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to build a value of a parameter and use the parameter. Kind of

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Table1 
    WHERE CONTAINS((col1, col2, col3), @searchText )
    ORDER BY(SELECT null) 
    OFFSET(1) ROWS FETCH NEXT(100) ROWS ONLY"
    , conn);
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchText", "\"*"+textToSearch+"*\"");
```